# Expand sap.m.Panel not working on tapping expandable icon on Android tablet

Tags: model-view-controller, sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm using sap.m.Panel to expand or collapse table data in XML views. Settings are as follows:

```
expandable="true" expanded="false"
```

The expandable icon on a desktop works as expected. The panel is expanded on first click and collapsed on a second click.

On an Android tablet the panel behaves not as expected. When I tap on the expandable icon the panel expands and collapses immediately. However when pressing the expandable icon, its working as expected.

How can I fix this issue with tapping the expandable icon?

Answer (score 1):

Though it is an old thread, I had the same problem hence thought of answering it. This is a problem with old version of SAPUI5 library like <1.32.9. This is not an issue with recent version.

Answer (score 0):

Please test this example on your Android tablet: 
[Sample: Panel - Expand / Collapse](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.PanelExpanded/preview)

You can also look at the source code for this example.

Above example works fine on my SmartPhone with Android 4.4.2.
Which is your Android version ?